# Teamviewer without GUI or alternatives for using just the remote IP

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ftp

I usually use the computer of the office from my house through TeamViewer. Today I realized that the only reason for do that is because I need to connect to the ftp server in the same network.

I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the process to connect from the PC of my house to the ftp server without the overload of the GUI. There is a bridge or something like that to do use the IP of the office PC?

Comment: I am thinking about a vpn, or open the ftp server on the Internet and restrict access to it from your home public only

Comment: Thank you @user2196728 but I don't have access to manage the ftp server, just the PC at the office. Also I don't know how TeamViewer link the connection. I'm not able to ping each other.

Comment: Do you have Firewall access ?

Comment: @user2196728 No, I don't. But if I'm not wrong we don't use it. But all the connections are via proxy, we need to configure it to every app, but it is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start OpenVPN server on the host in the office and then connect to it from the home machine. That is the most secure and reliable solution.

Comment: Can OpenVPN help me to link both computers? I can't ping each other. TeamViewer connect them somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: Teamviewer uses standard http protocol over port 80. That's why it passes most Firewall (IPS features on Firewalls are able to block this kind of software, but they are most often not implemented in small/middle size corparation)

Comment: Also TV uses intermediate servers to establish the link. Therefore if the office host hasn't direct link to the internet, things can be quite complicated.

Comment: `Can OpenVPN help me to link both computers?`, yes it could. But maybe (quite sure) you will have to do some Firewall adjustements, or change standard openVPN port...

Comment: I will give it a try!

Comment: The OpenVPN setup looks hard, especially because I don't have control over the firewall and can't specify which ports use. It is like the two PC's were in private networks not accessible from outside. Teamviewer must create a bridge or something to link them.

Comment: Yes, OpenVPN setup is not so easy, but you don't need Firewall access to specify port to use. This is done on server and client side into OpenVPN config files